# Input element unable to set with default value in mat-form-field

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, mat-form-field

I want my input element in the `<mat-form-field>` to have a default value, but it doesn't work! I tested the input without `<mat-form-field>` and it works correctly.

.html

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="time_field">
    <mat-label>{{ minute | async}}</mat-label>
    <input matInput type="number" formControlName="minute_glow_periodic" value="4" min="0" max="60">
</mat-form-field>
```

.ts

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  minute_glow_periodic: new UntypedFormControl({ 
    value: this.data.element?.minute_glow_periodic,
    disabled: false 
  }),
});

get minuteGlowPeriodic() {
  return this.form.get('minute_glow_periodic') 
}
```

I expected my input element to have a default value but none of the solutions worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use the `value` attribute to set the default value as you are using Reactive Form.

You should set the default value in the form control, this can be done with either:

```
minute_glow_periodic: new UntypedFormControl({
  value: this.data.element?.minute_glow_periodic ?? 4,
  disabled: false,
})
```

or

```
if (!this.minuteGlowPeriodic!.value)
  this.minuteGlowPeriodic!.patchValue(4);
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-hyy3a7?file=src%2Fmain.ts)